# TestNG, only way i can get @beforegroups an groups to work is by adding @Test(groups="xxx" to my top method is this correct?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

It appears that my tests will only run when I also assign my top method to a group. Is this the correct way to do things? It seems in examples that the top-level method does not require a group to be added. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package Practice;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeGroups;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

//This has to be added to allow the groups to be selected in xml and to allow @beforegroups to run
@Test(groups="Home") 
public class PracticeTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    String baseurl = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php";
    String womenurl = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=3&controller=category";
    String contacturl = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=contact";

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {      
        //set up driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Documents\\chromeDriver91\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("before test");

    }       
    
    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {   
        //close window
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("after test");
    }   
    
    @BeforeGroups(groups = "Home")
    public void beforeHome() {
        driver.get(baseurl);
        System.out.println("Before groups");
    }
    
    @Test(groups = {"Home"})
    public void Home() {
        //driver.get(baseurl);
        //driver.get(baseurl);
        String title = driver.getTitle();                
        Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("My Store")); 
        System.out.println("Home");

    }
    
    @Test(groups = {"Womens"})
    public void Womens() {
        //driver.get(baseurl);
        driver.get(baseurl);
        String title = driver.getTitle();                
        Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("My Store")); 
        System.out.println("womens");

    }
}
```

In my TestNG.xml I only choose to include the home and women's group. These both run and print out their statements to the console.

```
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
      <groups>  
        <run>   
            <include name="Home"/>  
            <include name="Womens"/>
        </run>  
      </groups>
      
      <classes>
        <class name="Practice.PracticeTest"/>
      </classes>
      
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: which version of testng are you using?

Comment: Hey @GauthamM thanks for the response, I have found the issue and will post below.

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself. This works the way I want if I remove the home tag from the top level class (practiceTest) and add (alwaysRun = true) to my @beforeTest and @afterTest.